# HTML file not working within a GWT/GXT project

Tags: html, gwt, gxt

The following code is working fine when I run it by itself but when I run it from within a widget in my project the alert does not show up. Am I doing something wrong or forgetting to do something?

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Upload</title>
    <script>
        function test() {
                alert("Works");

        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='file' size='30' id='fileDiag' maxlength='45'
            name='fileDiag'>

        <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="TEST" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please provide the code of your widget

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the content of your widget's HTML with just this:

```
<input type='file' size='30' id='fileDiag' maxlength='45' name='fileDiag'>
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="TEST" />
<script>
  function test() {
    alert("Works");
  }
</script>
```

You also shouldn't place JavaScript function directly in your widget's html. You can either create it using a UiBinder and specify a handler using @UiHandler in your UiBinder class, or create a class that extends a Composite and then use a XTemplates as follows:

```
public interface WidgetTemplates extends XTemplates {
  @XTemplate(source = "content.html")
  SafeHtml content();
}
```

Then in your widget's constructor you can add the template's content:

```
WidgetTemplates templates = GWT.create(WidgetTemplates.class);

public class MyWidget extends Composite {
  public MyWidget() {
    HTMLPanel rootPanel = new HTMLPanel(templates.content());
    initWidget(rootPanel);
    sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
  }

  public void onBrowserEvent(Event evt) {
    // handler for all events
  }
}
```

I didn't fully test the above code, but you might get the general idea. You want to code the GWT way, not to circumvent it.